# How can I keep a SceneKit scene from rerendering poorly when State changes?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scenekit

My parent view has a child view which contains a SceneKit scene, but when any state changes happen in the parent view, it resets the SceneKit animation, alters the model's texture, and makes the model larger.

Is there a way to keep the SceneKit scene from being affected in this way by state changes?

[Image of the model before and after the state changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBHE.png)

Here's the code for the parent view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var color: Color = .sBlue

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { self.color = .sOrange }) {
               self.color
            }
            .frame(height: 240)

            ModelView()
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the SceneKit view:

```
struct ModelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let model = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/3D Models/yBotIdle.scn")!

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        model.rootNode.childNode(withName: "yBot", recursively: true)?
            .scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.03, y: 0.03, z: 0.03)

        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        let camera = SCNCamera()
        camera.focalLength = 120
        cameraNode.camera = camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 2.8, z: 35)
        model.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        let directionalLightNode = SCNNode()
        directionalLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        directionalLightNode.light?.type = SCNLight.LightType.directional
        directionalLightNode.light?.intensity = 1500
        directionalLightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 6, z: 10)
        directionalLightNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: -0.4, y: 0, z: 0)
        model.rootNode.addChildNode(directionalLightNode)

        let modelView = SCNView()
        modelView.antialiasingMode = SCNAntialiasingMode.multisampling4X
        modelView.backgroundColor = UIColor(ciColor: .clear)

        return modelView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ modelView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        modelView.scene = model
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: We need to see what you’ve written in order to help you. Please hit the edit button and add your formatted code. You may get down voted if you don’t.

Comment: @Mozahler thanks for the tip, I'm a noob. I've included the code now.

Comment: Excellent! I've upvoted to help gain you some visibility. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! Creating an instance of the SceneKit view to use in the parent view instead of using the SceneKit view directly gets rid of the issues. I'm not sure why that's the case, if anyone can explain I'd love to hear it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var color: Color = .sBlue
    let modelView = ModelView()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { self.color = .sOrange }) {
                self.color
            }
            .frame(height: 240)

            modelView
        }
    }
}
```